# How do I manipulate data without save it locally

Tags: python, pandas, request

My goal is to get the access of some data from a website and put those data in the memory (NOT download locally) so I could do some further manipulation. Here is my python code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

year = 2019
month_str = 'Jan'
date = 2
month = 1

user = XXXX
password = XXXX

response = requests.get('http_some_url/%i/%s/%02d/%i%02d%02d.gz' % (year,month_str,date,year,month,date), auth = HTTPBasicAuth(user, password))
x = pd.read_csv(response.text, compression='gzip', sep = '|')
print(x.head())
```

The data is in the folder "year" => "month_str" => "date" with the file name "year+month+date.gz". when I run this code it returns

```
"ValueError: embedded null byte".
```

What's the right way to do it?

update:

```
print(response)
<Response [200]>
```

when I print response, it return 200, which means it has something in response.

update:

```
response = requests.get('http_some_url/%i/%s/%02d/%i%02d%02d.gz' % (year,month_str,date,year,month,date), auth = HTTPBasicAuth(user, password))
print(response)
x = pd.read_csv(response.content, compression='gzip', sep = '|')
print(x)
```

After I replace response.text into response.content and print, it returns:

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'
```

And here is some sample in that gzip file:

```
093013399690000|310001|C|A|59.85|73.15|A||
093030000913000|353701|C|A|59.85|73.15|B||
093100000411000|460501|C|A|59.85|73.15|B||
093130000630000|697401|C|A|59.85|73.15|B||
093200000464000|841501|C|A|59.85|73.15|B||
093230000508000|1013801|C|A|59.85|73.15|B||
093300000550000|1148701|C|A|59.85|73.15|B||
093330000394000|1313701|C|A|59.85|73.15|B||
093400000590000|1485801|C|A|59.85|73.15|B||
093430000495000|1652601|C|A|59.85|73.15|B||
093500000593000|1856201|C|A|59.85|73.15|B||
```

Comment: Take a look on [```gzip```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) module. That will help you deal with that ```.gz``` file and you probably need to user ```y.content``` where  you are using ```y.text```.

Comment: @accdias it returns ```AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'```

Comment: How did you try it? Post the code, please. Also, if possible, post a sample of the contents of that gzip file.

Comment: Check my edited answer. Just tested it here and it works like a charm. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that your string formating is wrong.

```py
f'http_some_url/{year}/{month_str}/{date}/{year}{month}{date}.gz'
```

Comment: I did it in my way so that I could iterate the date later

Comment: @clement, What Florian is recommending is the of ```f-strings``` in the place you are composing the URL. But Florian's example is missing some integers formatting though.

Answer (score 0):

You just need pandas for that:

```
import pandas as pd

year = 2019
month_str = 'Jan'
date = 2
month = 1

user = XXXX
password = XXXX

gzip_url = f'http://{user}:{password}@some_url/{year}/{month_str}/{date:02d}/{year}{month:02d}{date:02d}.gz'

x = pd.read_csv(gzip_url, compression='gzip', sep = '|')
print(x.head())
```

And here is a proof of concept:

```
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 17 2019, 12:16:48) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> gzip_file = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/testfile.gz'
>>> df = pd.read_csv(gzip_file, compression='gzip', sep='|')
>>> df.head()
   093013399690000   310001  C  A  59.85  73.15 A.1  Unnamed: 7  Unnamed: 8
0   93030000913000   353701  C  A  59.85  73.15   B         NaN         NaN
1   93100000411000   460501  C  A  59.85  73.15   B         NaN         NaN
2   93130000630000   697401  C  A  59.85  73.15   B         NaN         NaN
3   93200000464000   841501  C  A  59.85  73.15   B         NaN         NaN
4   93230000508000  1013801  C  A  59.85  73.15   B         NaN         NaN
>>>
```

As we discussed in the chat, here is an alternative using `requests`:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from gzip import decompress
from io import StringIO

year = 2019
month_str = 'Jan'
date = 2
month = 1


user = XXXX
password = XXXX

gzip_url = f'http://some_url/{year}/{month_str}/{date:02d}/{year}{month:02d}{date:02d}.gz'

with requests.get(gzip_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(user, password)) as request:
    if request.ok:
        df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(decompress(request.content).decode('utf8')), sep='|')
        print(df.head())
```

Comment: Oh so I just put my username and password in the url?

Comment: Yep. That will do the job.

Comment: it still returns: ```
InvalidURL: nonnumeric port: 'password@some_url'
```

Comment: How are you formatting the URL? If you use the ```f-string``` from my answer, it should work.

Comment: I used the f-string as you suggested.

Comment: Do you have a ```:``` on the username and/or password by any chance? Can you post the exactly URL you are trying to access?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201801/discussion-between-clement-and-accdias).